# Properties файл в качестве аргумента JVM?

Tags: java, spring, jvm

Одно из требований к заданию по созданию CRUD приложения на Spring звучит следующим образом:

> Все настройки приложения должны находится в properties файле, путь к которому должен передаваться в качестве аргументов JVM машине (-Some.conf=/path/to/file.properties).

Не совсем понимаю, что имеется в виду, как это реализовать и зачем вообще?

Answer (score 1):

Вас просят сделать следующее:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

import java.io.File;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String prop = System.getProperty("some.conf");
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application .class);

    if (prop != null && !prop.equals("") && new File(prop).exists()) {
        builder.properties("spring.config.location=" + prop);
    } 
    builder.run(args);

    }
}
```

далее открываем конфигурации запуска и в разделе VM options пишем

> -Dsome.conf=/path/to/file.properties

Соль в том чтобы написать -D перед названием свойства, только тогда сработает System.getProperty("some.conf")

Answer (score 0):

Имеется ввиду, следующее.
При запуске приложения: `java -jar program-name.jar` нужно еще указать параметр `Some.conf=/path/to/file.properties`. Получить этот параметр можно будет в методе `public static void main(String[] args)`. Он должен хранится в массиве `args` с индексом 0

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Частично вопрос прояснился. Например, у меня будет стандартный application.properties c данными для доступа к БД, его я должен передавать в качестве параметра?

Comment: Просто не понятно, какой код я должен загрузить на Гитхаб, а точнее как его протестировать, чтобы удовлетворялось это условие? и как потом его будет проверять заказчик?

Comment: как проверять? хм, ну указываем один файл с настройками например для бд приложение подключается к одной бд указываем другой к другой.

Comment: То есть для проверки на Гитхаб загрузить в итоге код, который этот параметр будет вычитывать со String[] args, проверять на валидность, ловить ошибки? Зачем это заказчику, почему не работать файлом в структуре проекта...но это наверное уже лирика